# Twitter app OAuth with node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth, twitter-oauth

The following "should" work to post tweet with the contents of  `message` below, i.e. "Lorem ipsum dolor..."

```
var OAuth = require("oauth").OAuth;
const twitterer = new OAuth(    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                                "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                                getContext().configuration.tasks.auto_tweet.apiAccessKey,
                                getContext().configuration.tasks.auto_tweet.apiAccessSecret,
                                // getContext().configuration.tasks.auto_tweet.apiPostKey,
                                // getContext().configuration.tasks.auto_tweet.apiPostSecret,
                                "1.0", null,"HMAC-SHA1");
// ... business logic
const message = "Lorem ipsum dolor..."
twitterer.post(     
    "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json",
    getContext().configuration.tasks.auto_tweet.apiPostKey,
    getContext().configuration.tasks.auto_tweet.apiPostSecret,
                                        ({'status': message}),
                                        "application/json",
                                        function (error, data, response2) {
                                            if(error){
                                                failedTweets ++;
                                                console.log("~~~~~~~~ Failed to send" , failedTweets, "tweets" );
                                                console.log(error);
                                            }
                                            else{ sentTweets ++; }
                                            console.log("~~~~~~~~ Sent" , sentTweets, "tweets" );
                                            setTimeout(function(){
                                                sendNextTweet();
                                            },1000);
```

the result of the above, *with the keys populated as in the twitter app dashboard* is this error:

```
`{ statusCode: 401, data: '{"errors":[{"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}]}' }`
```

I'm at a loss here--this is within an app that needs to post to twitter as its own dedicated user, and it is not authenticating other users or anything of that sort, so I believe the `callback_url` is irrelevant... and in any case I don't know what the `callback_url` would be if it is required.

- I have tried swapping the keys used s.t. the constructor uses the `apiPostKey`/secret while the `post` call uses the `apiAccessKey`/secret
- I have generated new keys and updated the config with them.
- I have verified that the server time is correct

Also, the 'Test OAuth' button on the app settings page (https://apps.twitter.com/app/XXXXX/settings) yields a page with this message "Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!" on it at https://dev.twitter.com/apps/XXXXX/oauth. It's not clear what this tells me, however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the first bullet point was a lie. Most likely I "tested" when the app hadn't reloaded the swapped config. The issue was that the accessKey should be used in the post, and the "post" key (actually the consumer key) is the relevant value in the `OAuth` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

From : https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

> With Application-only authentication you don’t have the context of an
>   authenticated user and this means that any request to API for
>   endpoints that require user context, such as posting tweets, will not
>   work. However, the set of endpoints that will still be available can
>   have a higher rate limit.
>
> And it won’t be able to:
>
> Post tweets or other resources;

I recommend you to try use an node package for twitter : 
for example 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter

Comment: I'm not using application-only authentication, however. I'm using [single-user auth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/single-user) My goal here is exactly the use-case described in those docs--my app posting as itself and no-one else. And further, changing packages here is undesirable since I'm adding to and existing codebase that works, using the OAuth package to post tweets